# Connect Firefox extension with C# application

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, connection, firefox-addon

I need to be able to make an event such that every time a user loads a new page and closes firefox, I need it to call a method in my C# application that takes care of maintaining the user model. I know for sure I need to create some type of firefox extension where I use javascript to check such an event. However, I have no idea how I am going to integrate my C# application with the firefox extension. Can someone provide me with some guidance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll help you out with the parts of the question that I'm familiar with (Javascript based add-ons), and offer some suggestions for the other parts. Here goes nothing!

### Add-ons

Firefox add-ons easily provide the tools you need to detect page loads and opening / closing firefox.

**To detect page loads** you can register a listener to the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko-Specific_DOM_Events#DOMContentLoaded) event in window.

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){
    var url = event.originalTarget.location.href;
    alert("Oh yeah, a document is loading: " + url);
}, false);
```

Alternatively, you can register a [nsIWebProgressListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWebProgressListener) to listen for [location changes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWebProgressListener#onLocationChange%28%29).  This probably closer to what you want, since `DOMContentLoaded` is also triggered for iframes.

```
var listener = {
    //unimplemented methods (just give functions which do nothing)
    onLocationChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aLocation){
        var url = aLocation.asciiSpec;
        alert("Oh yeah, a the location changed: " + url);
    }
};
gBrowser.addTabsProgressListener(listener);
```

**To detect firefox open / close** you need to first understand how firefox add-ons work with respect to multiple windows.  When a new window of firefox is launched, you basically have 2 separate copies of your code running.  So, if you care about firefox **windows** being opened and closed you can simply do:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(event){ 
    alert("Looks like you just opened up a new window");
}, false);

window.addEventListener("unload", function(event){
    alert("Awh, you closed a window");
}, false);
```

But, most likely you want to detect **opening / closing firefox as an entire application**.  This is achieved using a code-sharing mechanism called [Javascript Modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/Using).  Javascript modules are loaded *just once* for the lifetime of the application.  So, they enable you to share information between windows.  Simply counting the number of windows opened and closed should be sufficient for this functionality.

```
var EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = ["windowOpened", "windowClosed"];
var windowsOpened = 0;
function windowOpened(){
    if( windowsOpened === 0) {
        alert("The first window has been opened!");
    }
    windowsOpened++;
}

function windowClosed(){
    windowsOpened++;
    if( windowsOpened === 0) {
        alert("The last window has been closed!");
    }
}
```

Then you can simply attach the aforementioned event handlers to call these 2 methods from their corresponding `load` and `unload` events.

**So, this is all great and everything**, but now you have to twiddle with the details of getting a baseline Firefox add-on setup.  Fortunately, Mozilla has provided a handy [Addon Builder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/tools/builder) to ease this.  All the code about (except the Javascript module) should be placed in the ff-overlay.js file (assuming you use the linked builder).

### C# communication

I'm a little less knowledgeable about the interprocess communication with C#.  However, maybe I can point you in the right direction and let the smart people at SO fill in the rest.

*I believe* **COM Objects** are a method of communication between processes on Windows. So, you could build in a [Binary Component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM/XPCOM_changes_in_Gecko_2.0#Binary_components) to your add-on to perform the communication. However, as far as I understand it, setting up binary components is much more difficult than a standard javascript-based add-on.  Either way, Mozilla provides a [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_build_a_binary_XPCOM_component_using_Visual_Studio) for setting it up in Visual Studio.

**If you want to stay away from binary components**  you are left with the javascript enabled components of the SDK.  This includes socket communication, files, pipes, a sqlite database etc.  This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774073/what-ipc-method-should-i-use-between-firefox-extension-and-c-code-running-on-the)  addresses exactly the question you're asking.  If it were me, I would choose them in this order.

1. Sqlite Database
2. Named Pipes
3. Sockets

(1) because there is a lot of code samples available for this, and would be easy to implement on both sides.  (2) because this would be the way I'd implement IPC if I were given full control of both sides of the application.  (3) is last because I hate that crap (maybe I'm biased from Distributed Systems in college).

## tl;dr

The page load stuff should be pretty simple.  Check out the [Addon Builder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/tools/builder) to get going with a FF addon, and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko-Specific_DOM_Events#DOMContentLoaded) to see about detecting page loads.

The C# communication is doable, and addressed in this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774073/what-ipc-method-should-i-use-between-firefox-extension-and-c-code-running-on-the).  I'd do it with a sqlite database for ease if it were me.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. I am very appreciative. I will try these out!!

Comment: I always try to help people out getting started in add-on development since there's not a huge community.  Shoot me an email if you have any specific questions that I could answer!

Comment: Just in case some of you had the same problem, I used skabbe's answer and it worked :) I also had to use Sockets in my case to connect to my C# app