# How to get firefox to reload user_pref without restart

Tags: c++, firefox, firefox-addon, ipc

I have created a Firefox extension and a C++ program:

The extension show some information on a sidebar on Firefox.

The C++ program edit some preferences of the extension in the `prefs.js` (preferences file of Firefox) when Firefox is in execution:

```
user_pref("Sidebarinfo.initialize", "true");
user_pref("Sidebarinfo.initdone", "false");
user_pref("Sidebarinfo.usageflag", "eng");
user_pref("Sidebarinfo.userid", "162");
user_pref("Sidebarinfo.originaltime", "1309061712");
```

So, how can I edit my extension's preferences when Firefox is in execution?

If I edit `prefs.js` when Firefox is in execution (and only in this case), then Firefox resets `prefs.js`.

Comment: It's similar but not a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774073/what-ipc-method-should-i-use-between-firefox-extension-and-c-sharp-code-running

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525428/whats-the-best-way-to-communicate-with-a-firefox-addon, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561378/communication-from-c-sharp-application-to-firefox-extension. You are approaching your problem from the wrong end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do the communication part that way. It's a settings file, no "communication file". You'll have to read some other file (not sure how far this is possible) with the extension or retrieve some url from a mini http server embedded into the C++ program.